# Get the session variable once instead of every page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I made an XML file as my language dictionary, and in base controller I load the right translation from the XML file into a dictionary then save it in Session and load Session in every View as following:

```
Dictionary<string, string> lang = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["language"];
```

and instead of the labels I use @lang["Edit"] or @lang["Create"]

it worked but I repeat this code in every view

```
Dictionary<string, string> lang = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["language"];
```

Is there anyway I write that code once and not to repeat it?
By the way I know about Globalization and Localization, but it is not about translating only, because i want to use that code for other things.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for you because your question mixes the terms controller and view. I'm going to assume you mean "controller action" where you said view.

What you probably want to do is create an action filter. Because you already have a base controller that would be quite easy, just create a method similar to the following:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting( ResultExecutingContext filterContext )
{
    base.OnResultExecuting( filterContext );

    if( filterContext.Result is ViewResult || filterContext.Result is PartialViewResult )
    {
        ViewBag.Lang = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["language"];
    }
}
```

Then in your view just reference it through the ViewBag.

```
@ViewBag.Lang["Create"]
```

The OnResultExecuting method will run prior to generating the ActionResult for any action that inherits from your base controller.

I added some additional code to ensure the base version of the method gets called and to make sure we only set the `Lang` property when we're returning a View or Partial View. That way you won't incur any overhead getting the dictionary from session if you're returning something like a RedirectResult or RedirectToActionResult.

Comment: I think I was not clear. Now the variable Lang will not be accessible in the views, I mean it will be unknown. which will make me try to receive it in every view again, and my question was about if there is something or someplace I write the code once and make the variable lang accessible by all the views

Comment: to be more clear, how will I access the variable Lang in your code, because I need to write in the view something like @Lang["Create"] and it will show the word Create in different languages according to the user choice.

Comment: Thank you, I had to make some changes in my code but it worked, I wish if i could vote the answer but i am just a new user.

Comment: You may not be able to upvote but you should still be able to mark it as the answer to your question.